# Random Image Order Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

Made a slideshow that changed the main background picture every 7 seconds in the js file. The only problem with it is that the order is random except for the first picture. AND I started messing with it, and now the picture won't change. Please help!

Here's my index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photography</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="topdiv">
<h1 id="title" class="title">Photography</h1>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button id="aboutbutton" class="button">About</button>

    <button id="contactbutton" class="button">Contact</button>

    <button id="picturesbutton" class="button">Pictures</button>
</div>
</div>

<img id="photo" src="pictures/1.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript"/>


    </body>
    </html>
```

My JS:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("photo");
var imageArray=["pictures/1.JPG", "pictures/2.JPG", "pictures/3.JPG",         "pictures/4.JPG", "pictures/5.JPG", "pictures/6.JPG", "pictures/7.JPG", "pictures/8.JPG", "pictures/9.JPG", "pictures/10.JPG"];
var imgIndex = getRandomInt(0, imageArray.length);
var isIntervalRunning;

function changeImage(){
myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imgIndex]);
imgIndex++;
if (imgIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imgIndex = 0;
}
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 6000);

document.getElementById("title").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "index.html";}
document.getElementById("aboutbutton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "about.html";}
document.getElementById("contactbutton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "contact.html";}
document.getElementById("picturesbutton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "pictures.html";}
```

Comment: Could you please post fiddle example

Comment: can you be a little more specific, whats going wrong with your code?

Comment: The page consists of a background image that is supposed to change to another image randomly; aka a slideshow. The JS runs the function that intervals every 6 seconds. In this case, for some reason, the picture won't change to another picture. Also, I'd like to be able to set the first picture randomly, instead of it always being picture 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified below code and checked on my local. Now it's having random images for the first image as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="topdiv">
        <h1 id="title" class="title">Photography</h1>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button id="aboutbutton" class="button">About</button>

            <button id="contactbutton" class="button">Contact</button>

            <button id="picturesbutton" class="button">Pictures</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <img id="photo">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myImage = document.getElementById("photo");
        var imageArray = ["pictures/1.JPG", "pictures/2.JPG", "pictures/3.JPG", "pictures/4.JPG", "pictures/5.JPG", "pictures/6.JPG", "pictures/7.JPG", "pictures/8.JPG", "pictures/9.JPG", "pictures/10.JPG"];
        var imgIndex = getRandomInt(0, imageArray.length);
        var isIntervalRunning;

        function changeImage() {
            debugger;
            myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imgIndex]);
            imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex >= imageArray.length) {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 6000);
        document.getElementById("title").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "index.html";
        }
        document.getElementById("aboutbutton").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "about.html";
        }
        document.getElementById("contactbutton").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "contact.html";
        }
        document.getElementById("picturesbutton").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "pictures.html";
        }
        changeImage();
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after set attribute.

```
myImage.src = imageArray[imgIndex];
```